# How to find page in folder when using master page asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

When my pages are in the main level of the solution, the menu item href can find the content pages. When I put the content pages in a subfolder and change the href path respectively it cannot find the page. This seems to only be a problem with MasterPages. Am I missing something here? I get the error
Server Error in '/' Application The resource cannot be found HTTP 404.
Requested URL: /Pages/Pages/Items.aspx

Why does it add another /Pages in front of my path?

Solution

```
Project
  +Images
  -Pages
      Items.aspx
      Library.aspx
  +Styles
  Default.aspx
  Site.Master
```

MasterPage

```
  <div id="tabdiv" class="tabdiv">
     <ul id="tabmenu" class="tabmenu">

         <li><a href="Pages/Items.aspx" class="separator">Items</a></li>
         <li><a href="Pages/Library.aspx">Library</a></li>

     </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="main" class="main">
       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
       </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </div>
```

Comment: that's why absolute paths (`/Pages/items.aspx`) or using the Server-Side mapping reference (`~/Pages/Items.aspx`) are there.

Comment: Remove the `Pages` from the `href`. The master page is a wrapper for the _.aspx_ pages, but you should use the relative path to the _.aspx_ page when you provide the links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer, use an absolute path (to the root of your site) or use `~/` to relate all pages back to the site root (latter being more secure and robust between server location changes).

Reasoning?

- When you're within the root (`/`) linking to `Pages/Items.aspx` combines these two: `/Pages/Items.aspx`.
- When you're already in `Pages/` you're now re-citing the same directory `Pages/Items.aspx` so you're getting a combined value of `/Pages/Pages/Items.aspx`.

When you want to link to items, have a look at the `Control`.[`ResolveUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) method. e.g.

```
<a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Pages/Items.aspx") %>" class="separator">Items</a>
```

Now, no matter what page that link is embedded it, it still will provide an absolute path to that resource (in this case, Items.aspx).

Comment: This does seem to work however I notice that for other pages in the main solution also have to use the ResolveUrl then. I did notice when it opens the page from the folder that an image in my masterpage is lost and the link ot the image is broken.

Comment: If I use ResolveUrl or Runat="server" on my paths then everything seems to work ok in MasterPage and ContentPages. Is there a advantage or disadvantage of using one or the other method?

Comment: @tszoro - for broken links, inspect the url at the browser-side, using "View Source" or the browser's developer tools. That should give a hint as to the problem, using the information in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

try like this

```
     <li><a href="~/Pages/Items.aspx" class="separator" runat="server">Items</a></li>
     <li><a href="~/Pages/Library.aspx" runat="server">Library</a></li>
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get error HTTP 404 Requested URL: /~/Pages/Items.aspx

Comment: u should specify runat="server"

Answer (score 1):

Use thge above

```
<a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Pages/Items.aspx") %>" class="separator">Items</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Pages from the `href`. The master page is a wrapper for the `.aspx` pages' content, but you should use the relative path to the *.aspx* page when you provide the links inside the master page (given that all your pages are inside the *Pages* folder):

```
<li><a href="Items.aspx" class="separator">Items</a></li>
<li><a href="Library.aspx">Library</a></li>
```

Another option would be to prefix with `/`, which will render the link by using the [root-relative link/root link/web-root relative link](http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/linking.php#root):

```
<li><a href="/Pages/Items.aspx" class="separator">Items</a></li>
<li><a href="/Pages/Library.aspx">Library</a></li>
```

Comment: This seems to work at first, but when I click through the menu items several times then it cannot find the pages again.

Answer (score 0):

If your tag is "a href" you must put `runat = "server"` with their respective `id = "lnkItem"` then the code of the page from the server side you should write:

```
lnkItem.HRef = ResolveUrl("~/Pages/Items.aspx");
```

If you are calling to another site you can use 'ResolveUrl':

```
Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl("~/Pages/Items.aspx"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a path like this.Include your Domain name.

```
<li><a href="http://example.com/Pages/Items.aspx" class="separator">Items</a></li>
```

Or
You should use XML file or website path file.